# Duda con CallBack JS

Tags: javascript, funciones, parametros, callback

tengo un inconveniente con el uso de los callbacks en JS, el ejercicio es el siguiente, una función principal la cual se invocará, esta función se llama "**constructor**" que en su lista de argumentos se creará el callback, en este caso será una función anónima, la función constructor recibe 2 parámetros, uno nombrado como "**identificador**" y el otro es la función callback, que para fines prácticos nombre como "**f**", para hacer referencia que ahí va una función.

En la función constructor, es decir, en el cuerpo de la función, se crea un array de objetos, llamado "**usuario**", el cual deseo encontrar el nombre que este contiene mediante el valor que se le pase a la función "*constructor*" al momento de invocarla, para ello use la función *find* para ese trabajo. Después de unas validaciones condicionales mediante *if*, pregunto si el resultado de dicho filtro coincide con el valor que recibe "*constructor*" como primer argumento.

Al momento de invocar a "*constructor*" y pasar el callback (*función anónima*) hago otras validaciones, para determinar si el filtro es correcto y dependiendo del valor que el filtro me recoja mandar un mensaje diferente, pero el problema es que no importa el valor que le paso, siempre me muestra la alerta donde se aloja el mensaje de *error*.

Desconozco por que sucede esto, quizá lo lógica no esta bien aplicada, de antemano gracias por la atención, envío un cordial saludo.

```
var constructor=function(identificador,f){
        let usuario=[{
            nombre:'Maricarmen',
            edad:45,
            id:1
        }]

        let r=usuario.find(function(valor){
            valor.nombre==identificador;
        });

        if(r !='Maricarmen'){
            f();
        }else{
            f(r);
        }
    }

    constructor('Diana',function(algo){
        if(algo){
            alert('El nombre '+algo+' es correcto');
        }else{
            alert('Error, nombre no encontrado');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no esta en el callback, si no en el find y en tu condicion, primero que nada, el find() lo que va a hacer es iterar y espera que se cumpla una condicion, es decir, que retorne true o false, cosa que no estas haciendo en tu comparacion, cuando escribes function(){} esta no retorna un valor por default, puedes agregar el return o usarlo como lambda, ya que estos por default hacen un return.

```
let r=usuario.find(function(valor){
            return valor.nombre==identificador;
        });
```

o

```
let r=usuario.find(valor => valor.nombre==identificador);
```

El segundo detalle despues de eso,es que el resultado del find te retornara el objeto si lo encontro dentro del array, por lo que tu comparacion de r != 'Maricarmen' siempre seria falso, ya que estarias comparando {} != 'Maricarmen' aunque el objeto fuera { nombre:'Maricarmen'} , lo que supongo ahi quieres hacer es simplemente comparar si es diferente de null/undefined significa que el elemento existe y por lo tanto que es correcto

```
if(r != undefined)
  f(identificador)
else
  f()
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ahora estoy realizando la implementación, ya funciona de menera correcta, estoy muy agradecido por el apoyo y por el tiempo que te has tomado para asesorarme.